# Push notification in Create-react-app (Web)

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, create-react-app

In my React App, I want to implement push notification.

What I've done so far. 
In the service worker registration step, I added some codes to initialize push manager that handles user subscription, now my app will prompt user to subscribe to push notification.

After subscription, from what I read, the final step is to register event listeners that catches pushes and listen to push notification click. Something like : `self.addEventListener('push', function() { // Some codes here })`

Now, where should I put the listener codes ? As CRA auto-generated the service-worker for production build

Answer (score 0):

[This doco](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/debugging-service-workers/#adding_push_support) suggests adding it after `fetch` in the `registerServiceWorker.js`.

Answer (score 0):

**The following solution works only CRA 1.x.x!**

As I understood CRA doesn't support extending its service-worker.js from the box.

I've found the following workaround.

1) Install the [cra-append-sw](https://github.com/bbhlondon/cra-append-sw)

```
npm install cra-append-sw --save
```

2) Add an extension file custom-sw.js to the root directory

```
self.addEventListener("push", event => {
    const data = event.data.json()
    const { title } = data
    const body = {
        body: data.body,
        icon: data.icon
    }
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, body))
})
```

3) Patch the package.json to run the **cra-append-sw** during debugging and building

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js && cra-append-sw --mode dev ./custom-sw.js",
    ...
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js && cra-append-sw ./custom-sw.js",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this, here is a good guide on how to achieve push notifications in React.

Guide: [Integrating Push Notifications in your Node/React Web App](https://medium.com/@jasminejacquelin/integrating-push-notifications-in-your-node-react-web-app-4e8d8190a52c)